# словарь из списка Python

Tags: python

Есть списки к примеру:

```
list_1 = [['1', '2', '3'],['1', '2'],['1']]
```

Хочу получить вот такой список со словарями

```
l = [[{'key':'1'}, {'key':'2'}, {'key':'3'}],[{'key':'1'}, {'key':'2'}],[{'key':'1'}]]
```

Подскажите, как мне его получить?

Comment: В чем проблема переписать все в цикле?

Comment: Что я вижу... число в качестве имени... не хорошо...

Comment: @A_Vaclav, спасибо что не смайлик:)

Answer (score 6):

Можно рекурсией пройтись по вложенным спискам и каждый элемент заменить на словарь.

```
list_1 = [['1', '2', '3'],['1', '2'],['1']]

def process(lst):
    return [process(el) if isinstance(el, list) else {'key': el} for el in lst]
    
list_2 = process(list_1)
print(list_2)
```

Или если входной список всегда только двойной вложенности, то можно банально в одну строчку:

```
list_2 = [[{'key': el} for el in lst] for lst in list_1]
```

Выдаст:

```
[[{'key': '1'}, {'key': '2'}, {'key': '3'}], [{'key': '1'}, {'key': '2'}], [{'key': '1'}]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Вот решение со вложенным списком:

```
list_1 = [['1', '2', '3'], ['1', '2'], ['1']]
list_2 = []

for elem in list_1:
    elem_1 = [{"key": i} for i in elem]
    list_2.append(elem_1)

print(list_2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Вероятно, вот решение:

```py
listA = [['1', '2', '3', '4']]
listB = []

for items in listA: # проходим по всем значениям listA
  tmp = [] # временный массив
  for item in items: # проходим по всем значениям items
    tmp.append({"key":item}) # добавляем dict в временный массив
  listB.append(tmp) # добавляем временный масив в listB

print(listB) # выводим на экран результат
```